# Merging Power Bi Tables based on calculated field... maybe using DAX

Tags: merge, powerbi, dax, data-analysis, finance

I have two tables such the Table1 has columns like [date,totual purchased,...] and table two has columns like [date, revenue,...], where ... is many other columns not to important. However both date columns are calculated feilds so that they are easier to be compared. Before there were in the formate that in cluded hh/mm/ss, whihc is way to uniqe for comparison, i just want to compare by day. Also revenue is calculated by the formula [invoice quantiy] * [purchase price]. So, I want to be able to do anylsis of these two with calculated fields and reports. And, the only way I know to do calculated fields on these two is with mergeing. However, I cannot merge on calculated fields.

So how to merge Table1 and Table2 by date where I can have the expense side by side with reveune, i need them to be merge by yy/mm/dd because if mergeing with the additon hh/mm/ss, then there will be to many uniqe values where merge might not go well.

What I have tried before is doing a normal merge on the uncalculated dated columns. But I tried to group them so that all transactions on one day collapesed into each. But, I could not get this to work. I also tried Union for the first time, where i pulled a subcolumn of dates and other nescciary columns.

I also tried a cross join, but somehow it made a bunch of extra data. Such that revenue showed up on dates much farther back then what i actully have data for.

Comment: Create a table with Dates, you can create a calculated table with CALENDARAUTO() for example and create a relationship from that table to you other tables, filter on the CALENDARAUTO table to propagate de filter easily